# Dar ID para um Jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background

Tenho algumas páginas com um jumbotron de mesma formatação em cada página.
Preciso que tenham `background-image` diferente em cada página.

Como posso dar uma ID para cada um desses jumbotrons, para poder editar seu `background-image`, sem mexer nas outras configurações tipo `font-size`, `font-family`, etc?

```
.titulo{
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: "oswald"
}

.jumbotron{
  background-image: url("../imagens/jumbotron/bg-mochilas.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: se forem em paginas diferentes, voce pode até instanciar com base nos ids da páginas se elas tiverem um id, #index .jumbotron... O fato de ele ser mais especifico, sobreporá as demais. outra alternativa é voce ter um class para cada jumbotron ex: class="jumbotron primeiro"  e no css .primeiro alterar a imagem pra cada class.

Comment: Michel, muito Obrigado pela dica! Resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa necessariamente de id's diferentes, pode fazer usando classes mesmo, veja:

```
.jumbotron.success {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.jumbotron.warning {
    background-color: #FF9800;
}
.jumbotron.danger {
    background-color: #F44336;
}
.jumbotron#beach {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: url(beach.jpg) no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
}
```

O seletor `.jumbotron.nome-da-classe` especifica um elemento que tem as duas classes, você pode fazer o mesmo com um `id`: `.jumbotron#id`, o uso fica assim:

```
<!-- Exemplo com classe -->
<div class="jumbotron danger">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
<!-- Exemplo com ID -->
<div class="jumbotron" id="beach">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Eduardo, muitíssimo obrigado.
Usei .Class com #Id
Resolvido! Ótima dica.